# Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux - ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library

Tags: android, linux, opengl, android-emulator

I tried install Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux accord this post:

[How to Start Intel Hardware-assisted Virtualization (hypervisor) on Linux to Speed-up Intel Android x86 Gingerbread Emulator](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-gingerbread-emulator).

I followed step by step. All check position was satisfy.

I installed `KVM`, here is check:

```
nazar@nazar-desktop:~$ sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run **AVD from Android SDK Directly from Terminal**, I saw next output:

```
nazar@nazar-desktop:~$ /usr/local/eclipse/android-sdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/emulator-x86 -avd ARM-Nexus4-18-xhdpi -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
-- Invalid CPU architecture: arm, expected 'x86'
```

Here is configuration of this emulator:

[image: config]

Why does this happen? Any suggestions.

Here is some system characteristic:

[image: pc characteristic]

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to click on flag "USE HOST GPU" and it work!!

Comment: I did this but result the same. Can you explain what this `USE HOST GPU` do? And how is this compatible with HAXM?

Comment: use host gpu, practically uses the processor hosting the vm, to emulate the processor of the device, in the management of OpenGLES. to me it works fine. see here  http://mattfife.com/?p=1304